# Add file to Docker Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, spatial, docker-registry

I am new to docker, and I have created a docker image for sparq spatial reasoning toolbox using pull   docker pull dwolter/sparq:latest, (Gethub: https://github.com/dwolter/SparQ).
The sparq catains set of calculus in form of lisp files, which can be used to do spatial reasoning, using the Sparq docker image in the windows docker.
The thing that I have developed my own calculi and I need to add it to the image.

I have tried to do that using the cp command but I could not. Because I don't know the path of the file indside the image, in otherwords, where I should place the file inside the image, also when place it in the main root of a container, and applied the command commit, it generated error: access denied by ther resource.

first question is :
Does the path in the image has the same path in the sparq application folder which I have already downloaded?

Also, How I can  add this culculi (lisp file) to the image in docker ?

P.s. I have also downloaded the folder which contains the application (sparq and all its files and folders) and I have placed my calculi inside the appropriate folder ( caculi folder and it works fine).
I run it using  Linux command line and it works fine, Now I need to use this application through the docker.
As I have the application on folder.

Can I create an image on my own based on the folder that contains the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sparq Dockerfile](https://github.com/dwolter/SparQ/blob/master/Dockerfile#L23) indicates the working directory is set to `/root/sparq`. That means, you should be able to run the following copy command in your own Dockerfile to place your lisp file in the same place you have locally, the place where all other Calculi lisp files are located:

```
FROM dwolter/sparq
COPY ./path/to/my/Calculi/file.lisp ./Calculi
```

Then run `docker build .` to build a Docker image containing sparq and your file. Then, it should be ready to run.

**NOTE:** I am not familiar with lisp. If it needs to be compiled, the compile command will need to be added to the Dockerfile after the `COPY`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark this as answered for benefit of the community.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh I have already did that :)